# Make ajax call to a php function include on same page

Tags: php, ajax

My question might sound old and already answered to you but I did not find a satisfying answer to my question. Let me explain my scenario clearly,

I got index.php like this

**index.php**

```
<?php   
    inlcude("connect.php");   
    include("functions.php");   
?>

<html>   
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('#button').click(function() {    
            $.ajax({    
                type: 'GET',    
                data: 'method=test',    
                success: function(data) {    
                    alert(data);    
                }
            });    
        });    
    });
</html>
```

I did not pass the URL in the ajax call and I got the data alert successfully but the entire page from `<html>` to `</html>`. When I provide the url to functions.php I get the expected output in the alert box.

I hope you guyz have a close guess about my question. My question is I need to call a function from `functions.php` which is already included in my `index.php` page. I don't wanna use `functions.php` again in the ajax 'URL: ' as `functions.php` would be called twice. This is to avoid server load.

Let me the you guyz come up with interesting ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt the server load issue would be a problem unless functions.php is very large.  In any case, you are still going to have to make an HTTP request to handle the ajax, nyet? If you are really keen to keep server load low, you might like to implement your function in JS unless it needs DB access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on what Quentin said, You can't directly call a php function from an Ajax request but you can pass over GET & POST Data to a php script and perform an if or switch statement to call your function, so you could do something like this...

//Your Ajax Call

```
$.ajax(
{

      type:'GET',
      url:'functions.php',
      data:"function_to_call=0", 
      success: function(data){
        alert('successful');
}

});
```

And your PHP functions script would look something like this

```
     switch ($_GET['function_to_call']) 
     {

         case 0:
         {   
               function1();
               break;
         }

        case 1: 
        {
              function2();
              break;
        }
        default: break;

     }

//And your functions. 

    function function1() {
         echo "This is function 1";
    }
    function function2() {
         echo "This is function 2";
}
```

Comment: Assuming that functions.php has already been loaded into index.php, is there any possibility that I don't use the URL but use the preloaded functions from index.php ?

Comment: apologise if I miss understand your question, but The point of an Ajax call is to load dynamic data from your server... If you already have the data loaded then why would you want to make an Ajax call to that data? You can call any function in "functions.php" from index.php without an Ajax call...

Comment: But is it possible to fetch data and display dynamically from the preloaded functions.php without reloading the page?

Answer (score 2):

Ajax allows you to make an HTTP request. HTTP requests go to URLs, not functions.

You can write a PHP script which will call a specific function (and nothing else), place it at a given URL, and then use Ajax to request that URL.

You can make that PHP script consist of an `if` statement that examines GET or POST data and then calls a different function depending on the values.

You can't specify an arbitrary function from the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like this, you can call "a function" on the same page as you are on. 
What you do is in fact call a post on the same page. Bit of a hack, but it works.

```
$("#id").event(function(){
    $.post(
            "", 
            {postterm: postvalue, another:parameter}, 
        );
});
```

Then call it with a post:

```
if(isset($_POST['postterm'])){
    $othervalue = $_POST['another'];
    //Do your function
}
```